# How to compare two results and rank them according to the number of matching numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a beginner with Python. 
I am making a lottery program. I have a problematic part and ask a question. First, before running the lottery program, I will set six variables. These variables are compared to six randomly selected numbers in the lottery program. I want to compare the two results and rank them according to the number of matches.

My Criteria for ranking is :

- 1st : Match the 6 numbers.
- 2nd : 5 numbers match and one additional number matche.
- 3rd : Match the 5 numbers.
- 4th : Match the 4 numbers.
- 5th : Match the 3 numbers.

But it did not work out as expected. I do not know what problem is wrong. Please let me know where the problem is. Please also tell me how to fix it.
I hope I had the problem has been well explained.

Thank you in advance.

```
## Variable declaration part ##
print("\nPlease enter the 6 numbers you expected..")
print("--------------------------------------------------------")

while True :
    a = int(input("1st expected number : "))
    if a == 0 :
        print("0 is the excluded number. Please re-enter.")
        continue
    elif a < 46 :
        break
print("Please enter a number from 1 to 45.")

while True :
    b = int(input("\2nd expected number : "))
    if b == 0 :
        print("0 is the excluded number. Please re-enter.")
        continue
    elif b == a :
        print("Duplicate numbers. Please re-enter.")
        continue
    elif b < 46 :
        break
    print("Please enter a number from 1 to 45.")

while True :
    c = int(input("\n3rd expected number : "))
    if c == 0 :
        print("0 is the excluded number. Please re-enter.")
    elif c == a :
        print("Duplicate numbers. Please re-enter.")
        continue
    elif c == b :
        print("Duplicate numbers. Please re-enter.")
        continue
    elif c < 46 :
        break
    print("Please enter a number from 1 to 45.")

while True :
    d = int(input("\n4th expected number : "))
    if d == 0 :
        print("0 is the excluded number. Please re-enter.")
        continue
    elif d == a :
        print("Duplicate numbers. Please re-enter.")
        continue
    elif d == b :
        print("Duplicate numbers. Please re-enter.")
        continue
    elif d == c :
        print("Duplicate numbers. Please re-enter.")
        continue
    elif d < 46 :
        break
    print("Please enter a number from 1 to 45.")

while True :
    e = int(input("\n5th expected number : "))
    if e == 0 :
        print("0 is the excluded number. Please re-enter.")
        continue
    elif e == a :
        print("Duplicate numbers. Please re-enter.")
        continue
    elif e == b :
        print("Duplicate numbers. Please re-enter.")
        continue
    elif e == c :
        print("Duplicate numbers. Please re-enter.")
        continue
    elif e == d :
        print("Duplicate numbers. Please re-enter.")
        continue
    elif e < 46 :
        break
    print("Please enter a number from 1 to 45.")

while True :
    f = int(input("\n6th expected number : "))
    if f == 0 :
        print("0 is the excluded number. Please re-enter.")
        continue
    elif f == a :
        print("Duplicate numbers. Please re-enter.")
        continue
    elif f == b :
        print("Duplicate numbers. Please re-enter.")
        continue
    elif f == c :
        print("Duplicate numbers. Please re-enter.")
        continue
    elif f == d :
        print("Duplicate numbers. Please re-enter.")
        continue
    elif f == e :
        print("Duplicate numbers. Please re-enter.")
        continue
    elif f < 46 :
        print("--------------------------------------------------------")
        break
print("Please enter a number from 1 to 45.")

## problematic part ##
winners = random.sample(range(1,41), 7)
print ("Lotto number for this week : {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, and 
{}".format(*winners))
print("The winning lotto numbers this week are", "%d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d" % 
(a, b, c, d, e, f))

if 'a, b, c, d, e, f' in winners :
    print("\nCongratulations! You are the 1st!")

if ' "%d, %d, %d, %d, %d" % (a, b, c, d, e, f)' in winners :
    print("\nCongratulations! You are 2nd!")

if ' "%d, %d, %d, %d" % (a, b, c, d, e, f)' in winners :
    print("\nCongratulations! You are 3rd!")

if ' "%d, %d, %d" % (a, b, c, d, e, f)' in winners :
    print("\nCongratulations! You are 4th!")

if ' "%d, %d" % (a, b, c, d, e, f)' in winners :
    print("\nCongratulations! You are 5th!")

else :
   print("\nNext time...!")
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: Normally you tell us the error and we help fixing. Please reread: [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to constrain questions to a [minimal verifyable complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part of your code is full of repetitions. Terrible to the eye!

Please note that the first 102 lines of your program can be shortened a lot, by using a `for` loop and a list:

```
print("\nPlease enter the 6 numbers you expected..")
print("--------------------------------------------------------")

numbers = []
for num in ('1st', '2nd', '3rd', '4th', '5th', '6th'):
    while True:
        n = int(input('{} expected number: '.format(num)))
        if n not in range(1,46):
            print('Please enter a number from 1 to 45.')
        elif n in numbers:
            print('Duplicate numbers. Please re-enter.')
        else:
            numbers.append(n)
            break
```

For the next part, first I suggest you to separate the 6 winners from the additional number, in this way:

```
import random
*winners, additional_winner = random.sample(range(1,46), 7)
print("Lotto number for this week : {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, and {}".format(*winners, additional_winner))
print("Your numbers are {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}".format(*numbers))
```

The next part, in your code had a problem because with `if 'a, b, c, d, e, f' in winners` you would check if the string `'a, b, c, d, e, f'` is contained in `winners` which is a list of integers, so that is always false.

Instead, using `set`s to check for intersection of played numbers with winning numbers, leads to a simpler code:

```
intersection = set(numbers) & set(winners)

if len(intersection) == 6:
    print("\nCongratulations! You are the 1st!")
elif len(intersection) == 5 and additional_winner in numbers:
    print("\nCongratulations! You are 2nd!")
elif len(intersection) == 5:
    print("\nCongratulations! You are 3rd!")
elif len(intersection) == 4:
    print("\nCongratulations! You are 4th!")
elif len(intersection) == 3:
    print("\nCongratulations! You are 5th!")
else:
   print("\nNext time...!")
```

Program output:

> Please enter the 6 numbers you expected..
>
> ---
>
> 1st expected number: 1
>
> 2nd expected number: 2
>
> 3rd expected number: 3
>
> 4th expected number: 4
>
> 5th expected number: 5
>
> 6th expected number: 6
>
> Lotto number for this week : 1, 4, 2, 9, 10, 3, and 6
>
> Your numbers are 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
>
> Congratulations! You are 4th!

Comment: What you have explained is the solution I want. Thank you!